# Mongodb error : Can't extract geo keys from object, malformed geometry?

Tags: mongodb

I get the following error with mongodb 2.4.3

`Can't extract geo keys from object, malformed geometry?`

```
{type: "Polygon",
coordinates: [
    [
        [
            103.8324334524412,
            1.284232321447769
        ],
        [
            103.8342325475588,
            1.284232321447769
        ],
        [
            103.8342325469261,
            1.282433678236006
        ],
        [
            103.8324334530738,
            1.282433678236006
        ]
    ]
]}
```

Can someone help me understand the problem? it looks like a valid geoJSON object. My index is of type `2dsphere`.

The two steps i am running are :

```
collection.ensureIndex {'geometry' : "2dsphere"}, (error) =>
  # some error checking
  # and then
  collection.insert features, (error) =>
    # features is an array of geoJSON feature objects
    # {"type" : "Feature"
    #  "geometry" : <the Polygon object above>
      }
```

The insert query gives this error.
The complete document i am trying to insert is:

```
{
    "type":"Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type":"Polygon",
        "coordinates":[
           [
             [103.83243345244122,1.2842323214477689],
             [103.83423254755876,1.2842323214477689],
             [103.83423254692615,1.2824336782360055],
             [103.83243345307383,1.2824336782360055]
           ]
        ]
      },
    "properties":{"name" : "My location"}
  }
```

Comment: write here your find query

Comment: what programming lang do you use?

Comment: im am using node.js mongodb ntive driver

Comment: Is that the whole BSON document? If it's not the whole document can you modify your post to include a bit more context? If it is the whole document then that's probably your problem :)

Comment: i have added the steps i am running. The ensureIndex works fine. But insert fails.

Comment: tested it on mongodb 2.4.4. but the same error persists :-(

Answer (score 10):

The polygon object in geoJSON requires first point ([lon, lat]) to be same as last point.
By making this change:

```
{type: "Polygon",
coordinates: [
    [
        [
            103.8324334524412,
            1.284232321447769
        ],
        [
            103.8342325475588,
            1.284232321447769
        ],
        [
            103.8342325469261,
            1.282433678236006
        ],
        [
            103.8324334530738,
            1.282433678236006
        ],
        [
            103.8324334524412,
            1.284232321447769
        ]
    ]
]}
```

The insert query works fine.

Comment: Not just geoJSON but the well-known text (WKT) and well-known binary (WKB) formats that are used by spatial databases such as Postgis also require the polygon to be closed.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the issue was the same as above but the solution to that what worked for me is

```
point ([longitude, latitude])
```

I had just done the opposite like

```
point ([latitude, longitude])
```

That was pretty stupid of me, but really hard to figure out by the error
Can't extract geo keys from object, malformed geometry?

But just incase someone like me find this please check this as well.

Comment: And if it won't let you delete the records, remove the index form the collection first. Then it will let you delete the records.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and my longitude, latitude order was correct.
My mistake was that I had written `coordiantes` instead of `coordinates`
the mongo gave me this:

```
pymongo.errors.WriteError: Can't extract geo keys: {data}  Point must be an array or object
```

so maybe you have the right ordering but you have problem in your key names, make sure you obey the mongo rules!