# Exterior shell of polygon is invalid

Tags: mongodb, polygon

i tried to run this mongodb query

```
db.building.update( { "_id":ObjectId("53041776a2de55000079b4ba") },
                    { $set :                         
{"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[127.357858169667,36.36773567198263],[127.35825816966712,36.36773567198263],[127.35805432178199,36.3675356722397],[127.35825816966712,36.36733567198263],[127.357858169667,36.36733567198263],[127.357858169667,36.36773567198263],[127.357858169667,36.36773567198263]]]}}
                    }
                  )
```

result is

```
Exterior shell of polygon is invalid: { type: "Polygon", coordinates: [ [ [ 127.357858169667, 36.36773567198263 ], [ 127.3582581696671, 36.36773567198263 ], [ 127.358054321782, 36.3675356722397 ], [ 127.3582581696671, 36.36733567198263 ], [ 127.357858169667, 36.36733567198263 ], [ 127.357858169667, 36.36773567198263 ], [ 127.357858169667, 36.36773567198263 ] ] ] }
```

but GeoJSONLint test is a valid.

help me pls. thank you.

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using? It looks like your first and last point are the same; try removing the last point and see if this resolves the issue. See [SERVER-9240](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9240), which was fixed in the MongoDB 2.5.3 development/unstable release.

Comment: oh! it's working. i using 2.4.8 version. 
last and last before point are duplicate.
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error will occur if the polygon is malformed, for example:

- coordinates are duplicates (**the first and last coordinates have to be the same**)

1/2 duplicate:

```
 1/2-----3
  |      |
  |      |
  |      |
  |      |
  |      |
  |      |
  0------4
```

- if the lines of the polygon intersect each other (e.g. while trying to draw a pentagram)

intersection:

```
 1      3
 |\    /|
 | \  / |
 |  \/  |
 |  /\  |
 | /  \ |
 |/    \|
0/4     2
```

Duplicates are easy to detect, just check whether the first and last coordinate are are equal and remove one of them.

If you have an intersection in your polygon you can try and reorder the points (similar question: [MongoDB Error: Exterior shell of polygon is invalid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922445/mongodb-error-exterior-shell-of-polygon-is-invalid)).

If this dosen't work check if the [GeoJSON is valid](http://geojsonlint.com) (from this question: [Why is the exterior shell of this GeoJSON invalid?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82741/why-is-the-exterior-shell-of-this-geojson-invalid)).

Comment: first and last points MUST be the same, at least in pymongo 2.4.9. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17229313/mongodb-error-cant-extract-geo-keys-from-object-malformed-geometry .

Comment: @amwinter you are right, the first and last coordinate have to be the same, but if other coordinates are duplicates I think you have to remove them (although http://geojsonlint.com/ doesn’t seem to have a problem with duplicates - but also the error messages seem a little bit broken, so I don't know if the page is working properly)